# Delegate with nullable ref parameter that could be null

Tags: c#, events, delegates, nullable

It's ridiculous I know... But heres a demo:

```
class Foo
{
    // A lot of data in the nullable class foo.
}

class bar
{
    public delegate void FooHandler(object sender, ref Foo f);
    public event FooHandler FooChanged;
}
```

The problem is that I want to set 'f' to null in the event handler, but I can't pass null as ref. I tried this instead:

```
    public delegate void FooHandler(object sender, ref Foo? f);
```

But Foo is nullable, so that doesn't work. I then tried modifying the invoke method for the handler and set up a dummy null item to pass, which didn't work either. I tried using out instead of ref as out doesn't need an initialised variable, and that compiled but didn't run.

It's really weird and I've never really seen anything like it. I could change the Foo class to be non-nullable so I can implement it as Nullable, or I could add my own flag Foo.HasValue and do it that way... But is there no way to do it without changing the Foo class?

Comment: The general event pattern is `FooHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)`. What are you trying to solve by changing this pattern and setting the event args to null?

Comment: This can absolutely work - but you haven't given us the complete code for any of the options you've tried. I'll post a *working* example, but of course that won't show what the difference is...

Comment: Classes are by definition reference types and thus are already nullable, so it makes no sense to wrap them in a nullable type.
The `Nullable<T>` struct is designed to allow value types (which are, by definition, not null) to represent a null value.

Comment: @Paolo: I don't think it is quite sensible to say that value types are "by definition not null". Value types are by definition *copied by value*. There is no requirement that value types be non-nullable; nor is there a requirement that reference types must be nullable. One could build a type system with nullable value types and non-nullable reference types, if one wanted to be perverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can *definitely* work, although it's highly non-idiomatic... you say you've tried it and failed, but without the code, we won't know what you've done wrong.

Ignoring the event part and the first parameter, both of which are irrelevant, here's a complete example showing both `out` and `ref` parameters working just fine:

```
using System;

delegate void ByRef(ref string x);
delegate void ByOut(out string x);

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ByRef r = (ref string x) => { x = null; };

        string tmp = "Not null";
        r(ref tmp);
        Console.WriteLine(tmp == null); // True

        ByOut o = (out string x) => { x = null; };

        string tmp2;
        o(out tmp2);
        Console.WriteLine(tmp2 == null); // True

    }
}
```

Comment: you are right, I should have posted more code, but I imagined it to be a theoretical problem as opposed to a coding error. It turns out that was a bad mistake, as it was a coding error where I was getting a seperate null reference on the same line, and had assumed it was the  parameter.

Answer (score 4):

In C#, it is not possible to call a method with a `ref` parameter without an actual reference to a variable.

For example, if you have a method

```
void DoWork(ref Foo foo)
{
    foo = new Foo();
}
```

you can do

```
Foo foo = null;
DoWork(ref foo);  // works
```

but you cannot do

```
DoWork(ref null); // does not compile
DoWork(null);     // does not compile
```

If you want to make the `ref` parameter optional, you have to provide two overloads:

```
void DoWork();
void DoWork(ref Foo x);
```

The same applies to delegates/events.